# NodeJS Sequelize - Wrong direction of relation

Tags: node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I'm confronting on a problem since few exhausting hours on linking two models with Sequelize.

```
 var Ticket = sequelize.define("Ticket", {

    IDTicketBase: { type:DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
    IDStatus: DataTypes.INTEGER,

  }

associate: function(models){
        models.Ticket.hasOne(models.Status, {foreignKey: 'IDStatus'} );
}

 var Status = sequelize.define("Status", {

    IDStatus : { type:DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
    Name: DataTypes.STRING

  }

  associate: function(models){
        models.Status.belongsTo(models.Ticket, {foreignKey: 'IDStatus'} );
  }
```

This code produces the relation Ticket.IDTicketBase = Status.IDStatus.
What I have to write on my two models if I want the relation Ticket.IDStatus= Status.IDStatus ?

I want to produce on 1 to 1 association.

Thanks for the responses ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to produce on 1 to 1 association.

And here you go. There are no 1 to 1 relationships in a relational model. If you have a 1 to 1 relationship between tuples in two relations then this is just one relation, not two.

In a relation model a 1-to-many relationship is modeled by including the primary key of one relation in the second one and a many-t-many relationship is modeled by introducing a third relation that includes primary keys of both relations that you want to be connected. There is no such thing as a 1-to-1 relationship really. For example you may say that you have a 1-to-1 relationship between a user and her name but in practice you just include that name in the user's relation in the first place.

Comment: OK, I assume it's can't be bidirectional. But I can't figure out which instruction between Ticket.hasOne or Status.belongT I have to use to produce the right direction for the jonction in the select query to have Ticket.IDStatus = Status.IDStatus. I've tried every direction possible, added `references` attribute to the field IDStatus on my Ticket model but I couldn't get it functional.